# Supporting multiple industrial cameras from different vendors?

Tags: c#, c++, camera, usb

I'm working on an application that supports USB3 industrial cameras from different vendors such as Basler, The Imaging Source, FLIR, etc.  I can easily interface with the cameras using the different sdks they come with, but this makes the application bloated especially when I don't need all features. So, my questions are the following: Would most programmers just use the sdks?  If not, what would I need from the vendors if I decided to create a generic layer that will communicate with all cameras?

Answer (score 1):

many cameras support Picture Transfer Protocol (PTP) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol

on linux there is `libptp` ( https://sourceforge.net/projects/libptp/ ) on windows is *Windows Photo Import API* as basic communication stacks for PTP
( https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/996318/Using-the-Windows-Photo-Import-API-Windows-Media-I )

Comment: I looked into PTP, and it seems to be mostly supported by hand-held digital cameras like Sony, Nikon, Canon, and HP.  I've updated my question and added the brand that I need to support such as FLIR, TIS, Basler industrial cameras.